# Why is my slideshow not working in my React app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, w3-css

I have imported w3.css in my React app and I'm trying to create a slideshow with 3 images in the same directory as the component being rendered. I'm new to React(also web development in general) and am struggling with styling my app.
Code for Home.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "w3-css/w3.css";

export default class Home extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="w3-container">
    <div className="w3-content w3-display-container">
     <img className="mySlides" src={"./1.jpg"} />
     <img className="mySlides" src={"./2.jpg"} />
     <img className="mySlides" src={"./3.jpg"} />
     <div
      className="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle"
      style="width:100%"
     >
      <div className="w3-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">
       &#10094;
      </div>
      <div className="w3-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">
       &#10095;
      </div>
      <span
       className="w3-badge demo w3-border"
       onclick="currentDiv(1)"
      />
      <span
       className="w3-badge demo w3-border"
       onclick="currentDiv(2)"
      />
      <span
       className="w3-badge demo w3-border"
       onclick="currentDiv(3)"
      />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I followed the instructions here - https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp and made a few changes as I thought were required in my app.
I have attached the error I am getting on the local host page.
[The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxggK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<div
    className="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle"
    style="width:100%"
>
```

to

```
<div
    className="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle"
    style={{width:"100%"}}
>
```

Comment: Thank you, noob jsx mistakes :P I'm encountering another problem now. My images aren't being displayed even though the path is correct. (in same directory as Home.jsx)